# Copy rotation on limbs curl when character is rotated

Tags: rigging

The limbs on the ears, fingers, and feet curl whenever I rotate the main controller for the character. I checked for dependency loops, and tried switching the method of rotation to median point, individual origins, etc. But nothing seems to make any difference. Any ideas? Thank you all for looking at my question here.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay! So as it turns out, I was being awfully clumsy. I had a limit rotation on the feet, and was all upset when it didn't rotate all the way LOL! Also, I found out that I was using local space with parent for all the other limbs, such as the ears and fingers. The moral of this story is, always double-check your work. Thank you all for reading!